# Problem with quotes around file names in Windows command shell

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

I have Windows XP Home SP3 running. Trying to run this command:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\subwcrev.exe" .. ..\Modules\getbuildinfo.c Win32-temp-Debug\getbuildinfo2.c
```

It works fine (ignore the exact program and file names). However, when quoting the last argument, I get an error:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\subwcrev.exe" .. ..\Modules\getbuildinfo.c "Win32-temp-Debug\getbuildinfo2.c"

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When run without `cmd /c` but directly, both command lines run without errors. I used the `cmd /c` to debug a similar problem I had with `system` calls from a C program.

What is wrong with `cmd` here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what `help cmd` says about quoting:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
>   used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>          on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>          two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>          of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>          a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>          remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>          any text after the last quote character.

So double the first and last quotes and it should work:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\subwcrev.exe" .. ..\Modules\getbuildinfo.c "Win32-temp-Debug\getbuildinfo2.c""
```

Comment: This applies to [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) as well, so don't forget the extra pair of quotes around the entire command!